# select elements that don't contain a specific image with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

Hi I am trying to use jQuery to select all elements which have the class of "icon" which do not contain a particular image (to turn them off for filtering content)

I could do something like the example below, but it would seem like there would be a much cleaner way to select all elements that don't contain that image src to hide them.

Thank you for your feedback!

```
$('.icon').hide();
$('.icon').find('img[src$="'+src+'"]').parent().parent().show();
```

Comment: some html would help us greatly :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('.icon').find('img[src !="'+src+'"]').hide();` may work